# how to write regular expression makes sure that there is no digits after

Tags: python, regex

I want a regular expression that replaces `x**1` with `x` but there is a problem. I've written this regular expression:

```
r'\b[a-z][*]{2}1[ ]?'
```

but it replaces `x**10' with`x0`.

I want a regular expression that does this process and make sure that there is not numbers after `1`, like `10` or `100`.

Comment: I don't understand what you wish to accomplish

Comment: Post the actual input along with the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *negative lookahead assertion*:

```
r'\b[a-z][*]{2}1(?!\d)'
```

The `(?!...)` part is the lookahead; it states that it cannot match at any location where a digit (`\d`) follows.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG3hL4/1); note how only the second line is matched (blue).

Python demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\b[a-z][*]{2}1(?!\d)')
>>> pattern.search('x**1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10869f1d0>
>>> pattern.search('x**10') is None
True
>>> pattern.search('x**10') is None
```